# Backbone stops working if I remove view to separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Drives me crazy, take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/Sx77u/1/) - it is very simplified version of my issue but it's absolutely demonstrative. Like this it works, but if you delete AppView definition

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: $("body"),

  initialize: function() {
      console.log('init');
      this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
      console.log('render');
      this.$el.html("123");
  }
});
```

from "main" script (check yourself - the same definition will be still included in "external resources" section) - it stops working. I've tried to check with `console.log` if the definition is still available in global namespace, and of course it is. Have no idea.

**Update:**

And even more - it is not just *available* - goddamn thing work as we can is in chrome dev console by `console.log()` but `this.$el.html("123");` affect nothing!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. The difference between the code you posted and the one of the fiddle is the presence of `var app = new AppView` and the definition of `AppView`. Are you asking why the code does not work without the definition and the `new AppView` part?

Comment: @GiovanniFilardo yeas, but keep in mind that if you delete `AppView` definition like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/Sx77u/3/) - the same definition will be still included by external file - look at `external resources` at the left side of fiddle page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the bottom-right panel in your fiddle, you can see that the `AppView.js` file is included in the `head` of the generated document shown in the iframe.
The View is defined with the `el` element set to $('body')

el: $("body")

But the `body` `Node` does not exist, yet: it is an empty jQuery object.

Inside the `jQuery` `document` `ready` callback, the AppView definition finds the body element as you expect.

I understand your need to move the definition of the View in a separate javascript file.
You can achieve the result in many ways. The most obvious is to include the `script` element that imports it inside the body element. A nicer way could be to set the `el` in the `initialize` method of the `AppView` definition or, even better, you could pass the element to the constructor, as Kenan explains in his comment below.

Comment: Damn, it is that simple! I forgot that `el: $("body")` will be executed that early!

Comment: This is the issue. You can pass the element in and then it will work. `var app = new AppView({el:$("body")});`

Comment: @Kenan or I could set it in `initialize` function which seems for me to be a better way.

Comment: Giovanni, ha, I thought about that too!